# Change Error Message - Checkout Page - Failed Transaction

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

I would like to change the default error message when a transaction fails on the checkout page. right now it just says system error. this is too vague and I need to change this as customers are complaining. does anyone know where I can look to make this change in magento 2.1.7

Comment: you need to use plugin & override module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

Answer (score 0):

Override this method and update the text as customers needed.

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __($e->getMessage()),
            $e
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->getLogger()->critical($e);
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```